# event for selecting item with Tab key

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form in which the values of the input tags change when I click on them using `onclick="foo();"`. The problem is that when Im testingi it I naturally press tab to get to the next input box and this doesn't trigger the `onClick` function. I've tried `onselect` and a couple of others to no avail. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Example below:

```
<input name="user" type="text" value="username" style="color: grey;" onEnter="javascript:clear_input(this)"></input><br>
<input name="pass"type="text" value="password" style="color: grey;" onClick="javascript:clear_input(this); hide_input(this);"></input><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [onfocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onfocus) event, this will handle both a click into and a tab into the element.

```
<input onfocus="clear_input(this)" />
```

Also, you don't need the `javascript:` label in there. The browser will just ignore it anyway:

```
<input name="pass"type="text" value="password" style="color: grey;" onfocus="clear_input(this); hide_input(this);"></input>
```

And finally, you should read up on [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript), what it is and how it will save headaches in the future :)

Comment: This will do the job. But technically, `onfocus` handles a `focus` event only. Clicking on a field causes both `focus` and `click` events when the element was not focused, but only `click`, if the element is already focused.

Comment: I think I covered that with phrasing it as *click into* rather than click, but a good clarification to make nonetheless

Comment: This is all for show and the functionality remains robust with or without the javascript; albeit a touch clunky. Thanks for the link though, good reading :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use onfocus event. It works even for click or tab.

```
  <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">
```

I guess it would be helpful.